# How to check a condition after each line of a function?

Tags: swift

Is there a way to check a condition for each line of a function without needing to write a sequence of identical statements?

For example, let's say we are passing through a maze of squares, where each square may randomly have a coin to collect, whereas some squares may not have a coin to collect.

Is there an efficient way to write a function that checks each square for a coin, collects a coin if there is a coin, then moves to the designated next square? I only want to run the `collectCoin()` method if there is a coin. Otherwise, I just want to check if there's a coin and pass through the square if there isn't a coin.

Here's an example of what I perceive to be an inefficient method:

```
func collectTheCoins() {
    if isOnCoin {
        collectCoin()
    }
    
    moveForward()
    if isOnCoin {
        collectCoin()
    }
    
    moveRight()
    if isOnCoin {
        collectCoin()
    }
    
    moveLeft()
    if isOnCoin {
        collectCoin()
    }
    
}
```

For efficiency purposes, my objective is to only run the `collectCoin()` method *if* in fact there is a coin to collect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  your method `collectCoin()` always depends on checking whether `isOnCoin == true` then you won't be able to eliminate the condition but you could place a `guard isOnCoin else { return }` at the beginning of the `collectCoin()` method so that your code looks cleaner and without those repetitions.

Example:

```
func collectCoin() {
    guard isOnCoin else { return }
    // Your collect coin logic
}

func collectTheCoins() {
    collectCoin()
    
    moveForward()
    collectCoin()
    
    moveRight()
    collectCoin()
    
    moveLeft()
    collectCoin()
}
```

Also, if you always collect a coin after moving you could even place `collectCoin()` at the end of every of your move methods and get rid of those extra `collectCoin()` calls after every move method call.
You would get something like this:

```
func moveForward() {
    // Your move forward logic
    collectCoin()
}

func moveRight() {
    // Your move right logic
    collectCoin()
}

func moveLeft() {
    // Your move left logic
    collectCoin()
}

func collectTheCoins() {
    collectCoin()
    moveForward()
    moveRight()
    moveLeft()
}
```

Comment: Good, but the way you've phrased it is kind of a red herring. It isn't the _guard_ that makes this work, it's the refactoring of the test into the method. You could just as well make `collectCoin` consist of an `if`.

Comment: Yes, I guess this just helps with code repetition and will be useful when your code starts to grow but I think your desired functionality makes it necessary to check the isOnCoin condition every time you move. Given the circumstances I see no problem with efficiency.

Comment: Thank you @DanielE.Salinas. To clarify, let's assume the coins appear randomly on some squares, but not on others. I would not always collect a coin after moving; I would only collect a coin if a coin existed. If there _wasn't_ a coin on a particular square, then I would want to proceed to the next step.

Comment: Thats right, you would not always collect a coin but you MUST always check if there is a coin. That's where calling collectCoin() with the guard statement at the beginning come into use. If there is a coin it will continue with your collectCoin() method. If there isn't it will return and do nothing. In terms of efficiency you should not worry as guard is an efficient use of resources to escape the method as early as possible. It is also clear because the method would return early and describe the early return condition at the top of your method. I hope this helps.

Comment: @DanielE.Salinas in the second function you wrote, wouldn't it only attempt to collect a coin at the beginning, then move in those three directions without attempting to collect a coin between each direction? Your second function doesn't seem to collect a coin after moving each time.

Comment: It may appear so but in reality it will do exactly the same as your example. I edited my answer with a full detailed code example. Use this approach for improved readability and less code repetition. Just place de collectCoin() at the bottom of you move methods to always check for a coin after moving. Then you can only worry about moving around the squares because the coin collection will always be executed automatically without loosing any efficiency. :-)

Comment: Aw, that makes sense. Thank you for the detailed example.

Comment: Thank you too! If there is anything let me know, also please don't forget to mark this answer as selected if it resolved your question. Greetings!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221346/discussion-between-user3179869-and-daniel-e-salinas).